# Efecto visual en barra de navegacion web

Tags: html5, css, css3, diseño, navegador-web

Necesito de su asesoría para lograr conseguir el siguiente efecto visual de la siguiente barra de navegación.

[image: Efecto visual barra de navegación]

Lo que quiero es lograr es que los links de la barra de navegación tengan un alto menor al del logo para que resalte mas el mismo logo, justo como el logo de la imagen anterior.

Esto es lo que he conseguido hasta ahora, espero no ir por mal camino.

[image: Barra de navegación hasta ahora]

Comment: Hola Axel, tal y como está redactada la pregunta no queda muy clara cuál es la pregunta en sí. Lee [ask] para obtener consejos para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y edita tu publicación acorde a ese enlace. Por ejemplo, concreta la pregunta y añade un [mcve] si es posible.

Comment: Puedes usar el inspector de elementos (firefox o chrome) para observar cómo está hecho y poder replicarlo en tu sitio web, podrás ver el código html, css, javascript y otros detalles. Añado, que además firefox ofrece un visor de páginas web en 3D para poder observar mejor las capas y la estructura de cualquier página.

Comment: Creo que es mejor que compartas el segmento de código CSS que tienes hasta ahora, dado la forma en la que enfocas la pregunta. Además, dado que el que estás trabajando difiere del original, considero necesario que expliques que te faltaría por lograr según lo que deseas o necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo en la línea de lo que pretendes hacer.

Un elemento span se encarga de reservar espacio para el logo mientras la imagen se establece con posicionamiento absoluto para evitar que redimensione el div contenedor:

```css
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #666666;
  padding-top: 120px;
}
.navbar{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.navbar span{
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar .logo{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 60px;
}
.navbar .logo img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <span>Inicio</span>
    <span>Blog</span>
    <span class="logo"><img></span>
    <span>Contacto</span>
    <span>Redes Sociales</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buena, aunque lo único malo de esta respuesta es que el logo no aparece centrado en la página :(

Comment: @DanielDíaz bueno, yo creo que responde a lo pregunta del OP, que esté centrado ya es otro cuento jaja

Answer (score 0):

El efecto se puede conseguir mediante opacidad (RGBA) y el posicionamiento con flexbox.

Te dejo un ejemplo a continuación.

```css
body{
        background: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100vh;
    }
    nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    nav ul {
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        max-height: 40px;
    }

    nav ul li{
        padding: 0 10px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }

    ul li span:hover{
        border-bottom: 2px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .logo img{
        padding: 30px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Opción 1</span></li>
            <li><span>Opción 2</span></li>
            <li class="logo">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" width="100px" height="100px">
            </li>
            <li><span>Opción 3</span></li>
            <li><span>Opción 4</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```